# How To Restore Resharper Options from Computer

Tags: resharper, jetbrains-ide

With the release version of ReSharper, I made lots of ReShaper option changes. In each case, I chose to save those changes to my computer, rather than the solution or source control.

Unfortunately, I incautiously installed the 2021.1 EAP 9 version, then made lots of changes to those options, also saving them to the computer. Don't think that was a very smart move. This version, I think, is causing me all kinds of fits with code hints/completions, to the point where it takes many tries to code a simple method.

I am going to downgrade to the latest release version, but want to restore all those options changes from the options XML file on my computer. However, I can't find a means to import the file.

How does one do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to import an XML file with settings, then open the "Extensions | ReSharper | Manage Options" dialog and then "Import and Export | Import from File".